# How to assing a value to a variable with NULL value in SELECT INTO statement?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a query:

```
DECLARE
  id_tmp number;
BEGIN
  select id into id_tmp from ...;
END;
```

So there is a possibility that there is no `id` selected by query. And I have got an error:

> ORA-01403: data not found

How to handle this and assign `id_tmp` with `NULL`?

Comment: btw in your example, `id_tmp` is already null and so it doesn't need assigning. I appreciate this may just be a simplified example though.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, it needs to be reassigned in SELECT INTO statement, otherwise we have got an error "data not found".

Comment: Right. I just meant that if you attempt to assign a value to a variable and the `select into` operation fails, its value is null and you don't need another step to set it to null. But perhaps I haven't understood what you meant by 'a possible null value'.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, thank you! Made correction to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your query can only return one row or no rows, one way could be handling the `NO_DATA_FOUND`:

```
DECLARE
  id_tmp number;
BEGIN
  begin
      select id
      into id_tmp
      from (
            select 1 as id
            from dual
            where 1=2
           );
  exception
    when NO_DATA_FOUND then
        id_tmp := null;
  end;
END;
```

Another way, under the same assumptions, could be by an aggregate function that returns `null` when the query returns no data:

```
DECLARE
  id_tmp number;
BEGIN
  select max(id)
  into id_tmp
  from (
        select 1 as id
        from dual
        where 1=2
       );
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about [errors handling](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/errors.htm#LNPLS007). In your case you should be interested in the predefined error `NO_DATA_FOUND`. You have to catch the error and assign null to id_tmp there.